# Max-flow modeling with unified vehicle and commodity variables

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research, total-unimodularity

I am working on a network flow problem that involves routing through a time-space network. The network consists of:

- A single source node and a single demand node.
- A fleet of vehicles with specified capacities.
- A set of edges representing possible paths for these vehicles.

The primary objective is to maximize the flow of a divisible commodity to the demand node, with the constraint that commodities can only be transported via the available vehicles. Each vehicle has a limited capacity for the commodity it can carry, and while the commodity amount can be fractional, vehicles themselves cannot be divided. Transshipment of commodities is allowed.

I am trying to model this as a maximum flow problem to leverage the property of Total Unimodularity in the constraint matrix, which would allow solving the problem efficiently using linear programming by merely solving its linear relaxation.

However, I am encountering difficulties in integrating the routing of vehicles and the flow of commodities into a single model that preserves the Total Unimodularity of the constraint matrix. My attempts have included adjusting the network's topology, modifying the objective function, and experimenting with different constraints, but these adjustments have not yielded a successful formulation.

Is there a method to effectively combine the vehicle routing and commodity flow variables into a new unified flow variable? Because then I could model it as a max-flow problem, I believe. Or if not can we modify the network topology, objective function, or constraints to do be able to model this as a max flow problem?